# Creating a function that takes another function as an argument

Tags: python, function

I would like to create a function that could make the following snippet reusable:

```
# !pip install Faker
from faker import Faker

[Faker().credit_card_number() for _ in range(5)]
```

I have tried using:

```
def generate_data(faker_function):
  return [faker_function for _ in range(5)]
```

However `generate_data(Faker().credit_card_number())`
Results in the function being called once and copied

```
['4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639',
 '4852671922370639']
```

How can I achieve this implementation?

Comment: Because ```Faker().credit_card_number()``` is generating a new number. And the same thing. That is passed as a argument, which is added to the list 5 times

Comment: Is there a workaround to use it in the function?

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the point of the class `Faker`, rather than using a regular function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generate_data` should receive the bound method, not the result of calling the method, as an argument, then call the received argument *inside* the function:

```
def generate_data(faker_function):
    return [faker_function() for _ in range(5)]

generate_data(Faker().credit_card_number)
```

Comment: Passing the bound method also results in a list of bound methods `[<bound method Provider.credit_card_number of <faker.providers.credit_card.en_US.Provider object at 0x7ffb9c1cc4f0>>,
 <bound method Provider.credit_card_number of <faker.providers.credit_card.en_US.Provider object at 0x7ffb9c1cc4f0>>,
 <bound method Provider.credit_card_number of <faker.providers.credit_card.en_US.Provider object at 0x7ffb9c1cc4f0>>,
 <bound method Provider.credit_card_number of ]`

Comment: You'll need to call the passed function @Luke

Comment: Ugh, missed that part.

Comment: Well this answer is just what I was looking for ! Thanks @chepner

Answer (score 4):

You're passing a variable there, not a function

Try

```
def generate_data(faker_function):
  return [faker_function() for _ in range(5)]

f = Faker()
generate_data(f.credit_card_number)
```

Specifically, you pass the function *handle* then call the function as you otherwise would if it weren't a parameter

Note that this isn't the exact same as the first snippet because that's creating 5 unique instances of the Faker class, and this only uses one

Comment: Great Answer. But I was almost about to post the same!

Comment: The OP is passing the result of calling the method, not the method itself. Defining `f = Faker()` makes no significant difference.

Comment: @chep Agreed, but extracting it can be reused again, if they needed to configure the Faker for any reason

Comment: I'm well aware of this approach but failing to call `f = Faker()` would yield errors again

Comment: @Luke Please clarify

Comment: I'm trying to create a standalone function here and using `f = Faker()` will complicate matters in my task. Is there an alternative workaround?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `f.` or `Faker().` The answer here is that you need to relocate the parenthesis on the actual function call